# QlikView : get data filtered in pivot table

Tags: pivot-table, qlikview

I found a great tutorial for [building a nicer (dynamic) multibox, without extensions](http://www.qlikfix.com/2014/07/08/building-nicer-dynamic-multibox/).

I was able to use it, and I really love it.
However, I have an issue: 
if I use a multibox with a master detail table, then if I filter it from detail then master will automatically selected. The below example shows a normal multibox at the top, and dynamic/pivot multibox at the bottom:

[image]

How I can achieve this with my dynamic multibox?

For the label, I use:

```
=if(IsNull(GetFieldSelections(master)) = -1, 'Master',GetFieldSelections(master))
```

with this, I can set 'Master' as the label.

I can see data has seen filtered but I didn't find a function to get data that has been filtered to set it in the label, maybe someone here can give me an advice to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetFieldSelections()` will only give you the list of *explicitly* selected items. By selecting items in the detail, you're only selecting from the master implicitly.

Try using `Concat()` instead. This will give you the list of possible values for a field that isn't being directly selected upon.

Your next big headache will be how to determine when to show 'Master' or not. One possible method is to compare the full list of possible values in Master to the possible list. In the example below, I do this by comparing the possible count of master `count(master)` with the full list of possible values in master `count({1}master)`.

Combining these, one solution could be:

```
=if(count(master)=count({1}master),'Master',Concat(master,', '))
```

Comment: hi Zachary,
thank you.


before i'm trying to upload what i want to achieve because of missunderstanding but i can't do that because i don't have reputation.

after i see your answer then i can completed my script to achieve what i'm trying to do.
this is my script placed in label now.

`=if(IsNull(GetFieldSelections(master)) = -1, if(Count(master) = 1, master, 'Master'),GetFieldSelections(master))`.